# ActiveAdmin/Formtastic custom input (JSON)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activeadmin, formtastic, jsonb

I have a json column in my database (actually jsonb, but that doesn't matter here) table **items** of only plain

```
{
 "key1":"value1",
 "key2":"value2"
}
```

structure. No nesting.

The "keys" are actually foreign key-like integers pointing at **properties** table, which looks like

```
id | name
-----------
1  | Height
2  | Weight
3  | Color
```

etc.

I'm using ActiveAdmin for administration and want to have a custom input on editing an *Item* composed of a *select input* and a *text field*, which will allow me to:

- select a property from the properties table OR input a new property, and then
- type a JSON into the text field.

Can't figure out how though.

---

What have I tried and what my problems are?

I have created a custom input in app/inputs/property_input.rb:

```
class PropertyInput
    include Formtastic::Inputs::Base
    include Formtastic::Inputs::Base::Collections

    def to_html
        input_wrapping do
            label_html <<
            select_html <<
            text_html    
        end
    end

protected

    def select_html
        builder.select(input_name, collection, input_options, input_html_options)
    end

        include Formtastic::Inputs::Base::Stringish
        include Formtastic::Inputs::Base::Placeholder

    def text_html
        builder.text_field(input_name)
    end

end
```

Calling it as below from admin/item.rb

```
f.input :property, as: :property, collection: ItemAttribute.all
```

---

My problem is:

Right now, the select shows correctly the name of the property, but the text field shows just id of the same property. How to decouple these two fields and force the text field to save and read from the Item jsonb column?

Maybe it is important to say that I do *not* use ActiveRecord associations between Item and Property models in this case as I'm not sure if it even works with the jsonb column holding "foreign keys".